# Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 6 columns

Tags: android, cursor, filechooser

I'm getting an image file from the file chooser of Android : `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and I'm struggling trying to get it's absolute path.

when I select an image I execute this code :

```
GetInfos g = new GetInfos();
Log.d("URI", g.getRealPathFromURI(data.toString()));
```

this is the image URI : `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1112`

and the GetInfos class :

```
public class GetInfos {

    // The method getRealPathFromURI(imageUri):: Gives the actual filepath of the image from its contentUri:
    protected String getRealPathFromURI (String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);

        Cursor cursor = (AbstractActivity.CLIENT_ACTIVITY.getContentResolver()).query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            Log.d("1", "Here");
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            Log.d("2", "Here");
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
            String i = cursor.getString(index);
            cursor = null;
            return i;
        }
    }   
}
```

the `AbstractActivity.CLIENT_ACTIVITY` is the Activity which runs this action (public static variable)

and the Output :

```
2 : Here
E/CursorWindow(25787): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 6 columns.
```

Do you please have any idea about what's going on ? Thank you.

Comment: why do you call ContentResolver.query() ?

Comment: Well, because of the signature of `query()`, `Cursor android.content.ContentResolver.query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)`
  I did something wrong ?

Comment: What about openInputStream(Uri uri) ?

Comment: I have a function which compress the image and takes as argument a File, so I would like to get the absolute path of the chosen picture. Maybe this can be done some other way ?

Comment: why do you want to compress something that is already compressed?

Comment: I want to compress come pictures with the size of 2 MB stored on the phone, and since I'm browsing the sdcard it can be compressed or not compressed pictures.

Comment: Does openInputStream work? If so, change File param to InputStream

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work as I want.

Comment: does't work, you say?